# How to configure date render format in AG-Grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How can I set the render format of date columns in AG-Grid? When I look at samples I see dates in formats of dd/mm/yyyy, but my date columns always show up in a rather long format that looks like "Sat May 12 2012 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)". I would like a default format of YYYY-MM-dd with the ability for users to configure their desired format themselves. Samples I've found show how to do custom filtering with a comparator and stuff like that but the default works fine for me except for how the dates are actually rendered.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks,
Troy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is for Angular2+ version. If you are using moment library in your application. Then the job is really simple

**In your .ts file:**

```
    import * as moment from 'moment';

{
    headerName: 'End Date',
    field: 'endDateUTC',
    minWidth: 80,
    maxWidth: 100,
    valueFormatter: function (params) {
        return moment(params.value).format('yyyy-MM-dd');
    },
},
```

And the output you will get is:

End date: 
2019-10-05

Also for the ability to configure the date format for users: You can add a dropdown some where on the application and allow them to pick their date style and use the above valueFormatter and pass the function dynamically with many date formats available from moment library.

In case if your value is in string format:

First convert it in to Date and then use the above value formatter function

Example:

```
  this.firstTaskDate = moment(this.firstTaskDate, 'DD/MM/YY')
                .utc()
                .toDate();
```

Hope this will be helpful to some one.

Comment: For me, this way ends up in showing "Invalid date" in the cell... :(

Comment: @TheCuBeMan Then I think your value is string. You have to covert it to Date first and then use the above function

Comment: Updated my answer for your kind reference. pls check

Comment: I'm getting the values in as true Javascript dates (not strings) so formatting using the a formatter seems to be the most appropriate option.  Using a valueGetter is more appropriate if it's coming in as a string and I need to convert to a date object, but that isn't the case here and if I were to convert the dates to strings then filtering and sorting would not work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way around for this would be to use a formatter

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-value-getters/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I create a cell renderer for this:

```
cellRendererFormattedDate = params => {
   var date = $filter("date")(params.value, 'yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a');
   return `<div style="text-align:right;">${date}</div>`;
}
```

In your controller, be sure you have injected $filter.
In your columnDefs, be sure to define cellRenderer: cellRendererFormattedDate

Comment: Forgive my javascript ignorance, but what is $filter and how do I inject it. Is that a class provided by react?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had not seen your question. [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) is an angular api.  The link has detailed information about it.

Comment: Ah, I am using React. I thought I had specified that in the question but it doesn't look like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Although cell renderer and value formatter will work, I would use a valueGetter for a column something like this -

```
headerName: "Issue Date",
valueGetter: function dateValueGettter(params) {
  var date = $filter("date")(params.getValue("issueDate"), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  return date;
}
```

Above example is using Angular date filter.

The benefit of using a value getter is that sorting and filtering on such column can now be  based on the values returned by value getter.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the idea is to just return it as a string in the fetch from the server and that is what is displayed. I was able to modify my fetch to appropriately deserialize these into date objects already and then sorting and fitlering works. The downside to your approach that I see is that I18N or custom formatting would need to be applied at the server side before sending the results to the client. That may not be such a bad thing, but it makes the server side code lest generic if it needs to know who it's sending the data to and format it appropriately for each client.